# Authentication Issue with SendGrid

Tags: cloudbees

I signed up for Sendgrid via Cloudbees. I am trying to send an email via sendgrid SMTP API with the following attributes:

```
 port=587 
 host=smtp.sendgrid.net 
 username=[username generated by cloudbees, cloudbees_[myid] ]
 password=[the password i login to cloudbees grandcentral]
```

and am getting the following Exception.

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:823) 
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:756) 
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:673) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295) 
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
```

... 38 more

What should the password be? Is the username wrong?

Thanks in advance, 
Al

Answer (score 1):

Don't use your cloudbees credentials to connect to sendgrid, but runtime injected ones (read http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/SendGrid). You also should use resource binding to get Sendgrid directly injected as a JNDI JavaMail session, so your setup is even simpler

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong credentials to log in.  Cloudbees stores your SendGrid username and password in environment variables.  Access them as follows:

```
host = System.getProperty("SENDGRID_SMTP_HOST");
username = System.getProperty("SENDGRID_USERNAME");
password = System.getProperty("SENDGRID_PASSWORD");
```